# User Data is not running on EC2 instance in Private VPC subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, aws-vpc

This is the user data used:

```
#!/bin/bash
yum install httpd -y
yum update -y
aws s3 cp s3://YOURBUCKETNAMEHERE/index.html /var/www/html/
service httpd start
chkconfig httpd on
```

NAT gateway is configured for the private EC2 instance and also `s3fullaccess` permissions are given.

Please help me troubleshoot!

Comment: Is the yum update running?  Error messages?

Comment: Can you also check (1) if you can login to instance and check internet connectivity (2) if step 1 is good, check if httpd is installed? If both steps are done, do what bwest recommeneded: add some debug statements.

Comment: What is in the `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` output log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add some code to the start of your `user-data` script to redirect the output to logs.

`exec > >(tee /var/log/user-data.log|logger -t user-data -s 2>/dev/console) 2>&1`

Then you can use those logs to troubleshoot from the AWS Console. Select the instance, then Actions menu -> Instance settings -> Get system log. [Here is more documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-log-user-data/) on what to add to your bash script, as well as a video that shows where to find the logs.